# What am I doing when I initialize a property in the form let var : ClassName = {...}()

Tags: swift, initialization

I have this in my view controller

```
let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius  = 5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()
```

I am not exactly sure how the initialization within the curly braces works. Is this shorthand? If so, what would be the long form?

Note, I am just trying to understand this syntax more than anything, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you fix the title: let var: ClassName = { ... } ()

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function and calling that function to get its result. Then you assign that result (`view`, the value returned from the function) as the initial value of your variable `inputsContainerView`.

I call this idiom *define-and-call*, and it's very useful in exactly this situation, namely, you want to initialize a variable but your initializer needs to consist of several lines of code.

Comment: See my book for more info and examples: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#SECdefineandcall and http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_computed_initializer

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a closure that takes no parameters and returns a `UIView` and then you are calling that closure with `()` to get back a `UIView` which is assigned to `inputsContainerView`.

> Is this shorthand? If so, what would be the long form?

Yes, the full form of a closure specifies the inputs and outputs.  The long form would add `() -> UIView in`.  Swift is able to infer the inputs and outputs from the values passed in `()` and the fact that the result is assigned to a `UIView` constant which is why you were able to leave them off.

```
let inputsContainerView: UIView = { () -> UIView in
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius  = 5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()
```

You can read more about closures [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)